# React fetch failed: "TypeError: Failed to fetch" even though the API returns data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have a request to web API using React fetch but receive an error:

> "TypeError: Failed to fetch".

I set a break point in Web API and it returns the data without any error. So I assume the problem is the client site in React.

Here is my API (the project is Web API core 2.2):

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {            
        //I set a break point here and it return value below
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }       
}
```

Here is my fetch request in React:

```
testButton = async function () {
    const json = await fetch('https://localhost:44365/api/values/',
        {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
            mode: 'cors'
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(function(e) {                
            console.log("error");//the error comes here (e = TypeError: Failed to fetch)
        });
    return json;
}
```

Please help me to get the data in my fetch request. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
const testButton = async function () {
    const json = await fetch('https://localhost:44365/api/values/',
        {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
            mode: 'cors'
        })
      if (json.ok) {
        const resp = await res.json()
        console.log(resp)
      }   
}

testButton();
```